# How would i add an image to my canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I've been trying to figure out how to add a picture to my canvas, but everything I tried has not worked. Any ideas?

HTML:

```
<body>
<canvas id="gl-canvas" width="800" height="600" style="float:left"></canvas>
```

I have a separate JS file but I don't think its necessary to add it here since I can't figure out how to apply the function correctly.

I've been trying to apply something similar to this:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('gl-canvas'),
context = canvas.getContext('2d');

make_base();

function make_base()
{
  base_image = new Image();
  base_image.src = 'img/base.png';
  base_image.onload = function(){
    context.drawImage(base_image, 100, 100);
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if i have to create a variable for the '2d' element. thoughts?

PS. this is my first question, so, sorry if i did something wrong. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to append the image to the canvas using `appendChild`:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('gl-canvas'),
context = canvas.getContext('2d');

make_base();

function make_base()
{
  var base_image = new Image();
  base_image.src = 'http://via.placeholder.com/350x150';
  base_image.onload = function(){
    context.drawImage(base_image, 100, 100);
    canvas.appendChild(base_image);
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="gl-canvas" width="800" height="600" style="float:left"></canvas>
```